# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I need to pass a long[] from an Activity to an IntentService.  Created a Bundle, stored the array in the Bundle and then added the Bundle to the Intent.  In the IntentService, when i try to extract the Bundle, i get: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.`
As you can see, i've tried this with both a long[] and String[] and both fault in the same way.

In the Activity

```
String[] sAr = {"some", "times"};
// launch simulator threads using test parameters
Intent inStartSim = new Intent(this, SimService.class);
//inStartSim.setAction("TrigParm");
inStartSim.setAction("genData");
Bundle simBundle = new Bundle();
//simBundle.putByteArray(arSimConfig);
//simBundle.putLongArray("simConfigAr",arSim1Config);
simBundle.putStringArray("simConfigAr",sAr);
inStartSim.putExtras(simBundle);
startService(inStartSim);
```

In the IntentService

```
Bundle simBundle = intent.getBundleExtra("simBundle");
long[] simConfigParm;
String[] sAr;
//simConfigParm = simBundle.getLongArray("simConfigAr");
sAr = simBundle.getStringArray("simConfigAr");
```

When drilling into the Bundle object after the exception, i did notice that the identifiers are different:

```
Bundle[{simConfigAr=[J@5668b8a}] – in Simulator
Bundle[{simConfigAr=[J@f0d80de}] – in SimService
```

I know that there are many other ways to move data between Activities and Services, but this seemed to be the easiest.  http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3 - a good starting point for other techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value from the bundle you are putting into

**Solution 1**

Change this in you intent service

```
Bundle simBundle = intent.getBundleExtra("simBundle");
```

to

```
Bundle simBundle = intent.getExtras();
```

**Solution 2** This is preferred if you will send extra values from other activity too to the same service

Change this in your Activity

```
inStartSim.putExtras(simBundle);
```

to

```
inStartSim.putExtra("simBundle", simBundle)
```

Comment: Can you accept it as your answer if it works for you?